# How to detect duplicates and keep only one?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, select

I've got a table with lots of points (200.000). Some of them are duplicates (not exactly but e.g. a metro station has eight entrances) and I want to keep only one of these metro entrances.

I am able to identify the duplicates with the following statement (with desc_string = Metro Station Name):

```
--table of just duplicates
create table dups as 
select t1.* from ciss_poi as t1 join ciss_poi as t2
on st_dwithin(t1.geom,t2.geom,(0.5/111.111)) 
where t1.desc_string=t2.desc_string and t1.gid != t2.gid
```

Then I this:
[image: Metro duplicates]

The picture shows two metro stations with total 16 points. 
My question now is how can I only keep one point of each metro station and delete the others?
Maybe creating bounding boxes around each of the doubles would be a hint, but I do not know how to do it.

**EDIT**: Maybe this might another way of solution:
Maybe one possibility is to draw bounding boxes around points where this point have the same name and that are in a maximum distance of 500 meters to each other. 
I guess I can do with `st_envelope` but I do not know how to write the SQL query.

Comment: Are the points tagged with the metro station name?
What does the `desc_string` attribute contain?
Have you thought of using the [Select Distinct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) method?  This might work well since you've already set up a list of the duplicates grouped together.

Comment: @Get Spatial: the points are tagged with the station name in the [desc_sting] attribute. But what about points with the same [desc_string] but no duplicates because they are far away. How can I set the condition that it should select distinct [desc_string] from points that are within a certain range?

Comment: Maybe you could search the right distance to depreciate the coordinates in order to mingle thème and make a s'élancer distinct on it. Like "select distinct on ST_SnapToGrid(geom,10)"

Comment: Well, say the distance is [st_dwithin(t1.geom,t2.geom,(0.5/111.111)].

Comment: The ST_SnapToGrid does not eliminate all of the duplicates. What about drawing a bounding box around all double-pairs and then select only of the points in the polygon?

Comment: Which point do you want to keep? What if point a overlaps with b and c and b doesn't overlap with c?

Comment: I only want to keep one of them. Doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Your last 2 sentences are confusing to me.  Do you only want to "Keep one point of each metro station and delete the others", or "maybe creating bounding boxes around each of the doubles", indicating that you want not just one point of each metro station, but one point from each pair of entrances?  Please clarify as at heart, it seems to be a simple aggregate problem to remove duplicates using the `desc_string` field.  What are we missing?

Comment: Sorry, hopefully I can explain myself a bit clearer. If I have 8 points all showing the entrance to the same metro station and all are let's say within 500 meters I want to keep only one of this points. -- I could use the `desc_string`field to select only one point and erase the others. But imagine within the tables are 500 points where `desc_string`='park' and the parks are spread around the world but each 'park' value describes the northern and the southern entrance. I also want to keep only one parc instead of two. So only distinct on `desc_string` does not work. I need spatial...

Comment: ...calculation to cluster them and keep only one 'park'. The idea of the bounding boxes was to design bb around the pairs of nearby distance and use this bounding boxes to select one point and delete the other. Is this more understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pondering this all day, I think you are much closer to the answer than you think.

Your initial query showed all the points matching one station within a certain distance, but excluded the initial point.  This also excluded all points with no duplicates in the vicinity.  You did this with the `WHERE` clause of `t1.gid != t2.gid`.

Suppose you removed that from the where clause, and added the `SELECT DISTINCT ON` notation, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE allunique AS  
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.desc_string) t1.*  
FROM ciss_poi AS t1  
JOIN ciss_poi AS t2  
 ON ST_Dwithin(t1.geom,t2.geom,(0.5/111.111))  
WHERE t1.desc_string=t2.desc_string  
ORDER BY t1.desc_string, t1.gid
```

Here is the help for the DISTINCT clause:  [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

When you use this with the `ON` addition, and name the field, it groups by that selected field, and then returns the first record.  The record that is returned can be controlled by using the `ORDER BY` parameter.

In this case, if we return the all the joined records within a certain distance, including the initial record, then order by the `gid`, it should return just the single one out of a group, but also the individual records with nothing in the vicinity.

Comment: Thank you very much. This approach works! It would be even better if it would create a centroid of the doubles with the centroid's attributes the same as the double (like desc_string, etc.). But hey, at least I get rid of my duplicates. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks to both you and @hoge6b01 for posting this question and answer. 7 years later I came across this identical problem (duplicate station entrances) and this answer saved me hours of writing a Python script workaround

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility, using a slightly different approach. You can create a convex hull around each set of "duplicates" and find it's centroid to enter into a new POI table. Then UNION that query with all those POI that are NOT duplicates (not within 500 m of any other). So:

```
CREATE TABLE poi_no_dups (gid INTEGER, desc_string text, ...);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('poi_no_dups', 'geom',<your SRID>,'POINT',2);

INSERT INTO poi_no_dups (gid, desc_string, geom)
   SELECT t1.gid, t1.desc_string, ST_Centroid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(t1.geometry)))
    FROM ciss_poi AS t1 JOIN ciss_poi AS t2 
    ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom,t2.geom,(0.5/111.111)) 
    WHERE t1.desc_string=t2.desc_string and t1.gid != t2.gid
    LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT t1.gid, t1.desc_string, t1.geometry
    FROM ciss_poi AS t1 JOIN ciss_poi AS t2 
    ON ST_DWithin(t1.geom,t2.geom,(0.5/111.111))=0 
    WHERE t1.desc_string != t2.desc_string and t1.gid != t2.gid
    ;
```

In this way, when you have i.e. 4 entrances to a metro station, the final table will contain the centroid of the entrances, rather than a random one of the entrances.

Here's a revised answer, without requiring the UNION:

```
SELECT t1.desc_string, 
ST_Centroid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(t1.geom))) as geom2
FROM ciss_poi AS t1 
WHERE ST_Dwithin(t1.geom, geom2, (0.5/111.111))
GROUP BY t1.desc_string
```

Comment: It should rather be `UNION ALL` since you don't expect duplicates anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Micha, a very interesting approach. I especially like the fact of having a centroid as a new POI. But it still gives me back 4 metro stations.

Comment: Cna you test just the first SELECT statement (before the UNION) to be sure that you're getting one centroid for each cluster of near-by points?

Comment: I checked the first `SELECT` (had to add a `group by` on t1.gid) but it returns me the initial eight metro stations without any centroid POIs.

Comment: If you add `GROUP BY t1.gid` then indeed you'll get one row for every metro station entrance. They all should have the same geometry. Try doing the SELECT with AsText() surrounding the St_Centroid function to see the coordinate values. What I forgot in my first query was `LIMIT 1` so that for each cluster of "duplicate' points you're using only one. See the edit in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks Micha, but it gives me back 
`ERROR: column "t1.gid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL Status:42803
Zeichen:11` Well, then I need to group on the t1.gid

Comment: @Micha: Also, it gives me back that there is a syntax error at or near "UNION". Any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: I revisited this question (sorry for the delay) and here's a possible solution. If you can ignore the id values for each point, then this works:  `SELECT t1.desc_string, ST_Centroid(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(t1.geometry)))
    FROM ciss_poi AS t1 GROUP BY t1.desc_string`. No need for the UNION. This gets all the original points by their description, and GROUPS those with the same description together to make a convex hull and centroid.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting the question again. A problem remains. `GROUP BY t1.desc_string` implicates the following: Imagine four points `desc_string=Stadium`, two of them in the U.S. and two of them in Europe. By grouping them I get a centroid in the middle of the atlantic ocean. Any idea to get this solved? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, add on the ST_Dwithin() bit, checking that the centroid is near enough to the original points. I've put in a revised answer, see above

Comment: Thanks Micha, sorry for bothering you. If you prefer PM we could switch to sending eMails. Well, I tried the statement as you posted it in you revised answer, but all PG returns: ERROR: -column "geom2" does not exist-. Well, I tried to edit your statement but I could not get it running. Would you mind to help me once again? Thank you!

Comment: No idea? Every help is appreciated.

Comment: I'll try to have another look, but this week I'm too swamped. If you somehow send your contact details (in your profile?), we'll continue "face to face".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I guess you can see my eMail in my profil. Thank you very much.